# De normalize predicted value

Tags: r, normalization

Alright so i have found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range) really good answer on how to normalize my data.

I implemented @user25658 's code into my own project successfully, trained a linear model and used it to make a prediction.

Say `y = 0.4513869` is the predicted normalized value which i would like to de-normalize.

Based on the normalization code below, how can i achieve this?

`normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
denormalized = (normalized)*(max(x)-min(x))+min(x)
```

e.g.

```
x=1:5
x
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5

normalized = (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
normalized
#[1] 0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00

denormalized = (normalized)*(max(x)-min(x))+min(x)
denormalized
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```