# Population Weighting - Should I and how would I go about it?

Tags: r, weighted-data, weights

I am sure that this has been addressed in other threads, but after half an hour or so of looking, I thought I'd just ask. My apologies in advance.

I am currently looking at suicide rates/100,000 pop by county in a state. The county pops ranges from almost 1 million to ~1,500. As you can imagine, the rates in the smaller counties are highly variable. 3 suicides may result in a rate of 106/100000. I am comparing these rates across counties.

A) Should I weight my data to address this volatility?
B) What would be the best way of going about this?

Data are: 36 observations of suicide rate/100,000; 36 observations of county population

edit: This is part of a larger project creating a time-series animation of rates for counties over a 15 year span. Basically, each slide will be a heatmap of suicide rate of each county in the state. I'm trying to create a graphical representation of where rates have been high over time. Would smoothing be useful in creating a more faithful representation?

edit: Here's a version of the time series graphic I'm working on. I would like to remove the volatility of the smaller counties - i.e. make it look less jumpy with the extremes brought more into line. I am relatively inexpert when it come to hard modelling in r, so something simple perhaps if it can retain the overall integrity of the data?

[image: Rate of Suicide by Firearm, Oregon, 2001-2015]

Comment: Because "looking at" is a vague statement of your objectives, could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is part of a larger project creating a time-series animation of rates for counties over a 15 year span. Basically, each slide will be a heatmap of suicide rate of each county in the state. I'm trying to create a graphical representation of where rates have been high over time.

Comment: Please include that important information within the post itself: it opens up the possibility of many more solutions, such as smoothing the series over time.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that I just needed to normalize my data. Utilized the answer from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range). That did the trick! Stats skills are definitely in need of a refresher...

Comment: Unfortunately, normalizing the data does not solve the problem you asked: the counties with smaller populations will continue to exhibit greater volatility.

Comment: Was weighting a better solution, then?