# How to normalize rating in scale of 1 to 5?

Tags: normalization, recommender-system, rating

Can anyone please tell me How to normalize rating in a scale of 1 to 5?

In Yahoo! Movies dataset user has given a rating to a movie on the scale of 1 to 13 and 0 means there is no rating to that movie.

Please tell me how to normalize it.. original rating in scale of 1 to 13 
the new rating that needed in the program is 1 to 5.

Comment: I think your question is already answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard re-scaling formula, i.e. $value_{new} = \frac{max_{new} - min_{new}}{max_{old} - min_{old}}\times (value_{old} - max_{old}) + max_{new}$.

In your case, that would be $\frac{5-1}{13-1} \times (value_{old} - 13) + 5$. And $value_{old} = 0 = value_{new}$.

Comment: Usually, "a scale of 1 to 5" means the values are *integral*.  Your solution does not produce integral values.  The obvious solution is to round the results, but there are difficulties.  The most problematic issue is that since $13/5$ is not integral, the number of original ratings that map to a new rating will vary between $2$ and $3$, thereby potentially creating some bias.  That needs to be understood and, perhaps, controlled in some way.