# what is a scoring technique for an individual variable?

Tags: data-transformation

i have to score my data fro scale 0 to 10 on the basis of the variable value for each year.

i.e data of GDP per capita growth rate ,if the value of GDP per capita growth for a specific year is 3.25 how can i transform this value into scoring 0 to 10.

Comment: One possibility is MinMax scaling, e.g. in R, this shall be along `function(x){(10*x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}`

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to normalize data each with its own assumptions about the data. I'm guessing an approach similar to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range) would work for you. That is:
$$z_i=\frac{10(x_i-\min(x))}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$$