# How to scale data to desired range?

Tags: data-transformation, range

I have a table with 3 columns X, Y and Z with n rows.

The range of the data is 0-255. But I wished to scale the values such that the range becomes from -p to +q (where I decide p and q). I randomly came upon a conversion like this one:

[image]

on this [site](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/color-matching-function). I don't remember which matrix exactly did I use.

Now this is how it changed the range (**Blue: Initial range,  Orange: New Range, Ignore the Grey one**)

[image: Blue: Initial range, Orange: New Range, Ignore the Grey one]

How can I control this process of changing the range?

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/20221) to another question might address your issue.

Comment: @deemel Neither Normalization nor Standardization can scale the entire range into a custom range. Thanks btw

Comment: On the contrary, both can do it.  The duplicate explicitly answers the question (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/919)--but you can find a large number of other (equivalent) answers here, too.